# Remove AppTests from Targets

Tags: iphone

In the project it shows two targets. One is main target that is application and another is app test. I need only one target that is main application only. So how to remove AppTests from Targets.

Answer (score 0):

The method to remove AppTests from Targets is to select AppTests and then click on BuildPhases 
and in Build Phases Under Target Dependencies remove the dependency which is main app and after that click Analyze under Product menu and then you can right click AppTest and then click Delete and it will finally delete AppTests from the target and then it will show only one target in your project.